# A guide in reading in a file

Tags: java, file

I have a question about file reading and writing since I learned about them recently.

If I have file contains a data like:

```
1 apartment 600000 2 house 500000 3 house 1000 4 something 5456564
```

(id name price/int string double)

That's all in 1 line,

Can I do something like `instanceof` so that I can calculate the prices of 1 type
like all the prices of houses?

Comment: Is this Java? (based on `instanceof`). It's rather difficult to understand the question. This might answer your question - `instanceof` is for checking whether an object is of a certain type, you can't use it to compare strings with one another (strings all have the same type - `String` (in Java)). But you can use `yourString.equals("house")`.

Comment: Oh sorry to forget to state the language, yes it's Java. and i'm familiar to FileReader, BufferedReader and using Scanner to read files along while-loop to read lines. don't know about yourString.equals("house")

Comment: There are many guides, both on file reading and instanceof. There is not need to ask this question. It won't help andybody.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear to me how you are currently storing the data you read in, but what you should be doing is reading the data into a List of some data object:

```
public class Dwelling
{
    int Id;
    String name;
    int price;
}
```

Then store these in some data structure.  I think a HashMap of ArrayLists might be convenient for your purposes:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Dwelling>> types = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Dwelling>>();

// Loop through records in file
while(moreRecords)
{
    // Read the next record into a data object
    DwellingType d = getNextDwelling();

    // Store the record in the data structure
    ArrayList<Dwelling> list = types.get(d.getName());
    if (list == null)
    {
        list = new ArrayList<Dwelling>();
        types.put(d.getName(), list);
    }
    list.add(d);
}
```

To access the list of records of a particular type, you'd just call `HashMap.get()`:

```
ArrayList<Dwelling> list = types.get("Apartment");
```

Then you could just loop through the records to do whatever you need to do:

```
int totalPrice = 0;
for (Dwelling d : list)
{
    totalPrice += d.price;
}
```